# Generating graphs for emailing from console application using highcharts

Tags: c#, .net, email, graph, highcharts

I currently have an MVC.NET website that uses Highcharts to do some fancy graphs.   There is also an overnight console application that uses the same database (as the website) to send out emails to all registered users.

We have now had a change request come in that the customer would like to send out the same looking graphs that the website generates via the overnight email, instead of the table it currently sends the data as.

My initial investigations showed that potentially I could generate an image and send that.  However, I can't find anywhere that indicates how i might do this via .NET.  All the examples seem to use something else i.e. PHP or Java.

Does anyone know how it might be possible using a .NET console application to generate an image using Highcharts.

Or if it's not possible through Highcharts are there any other graphing libraries that would be suitable (or as visually appealing to Highcharts) for this?

Comment: In the Highcharts you can return a SVG by (getSVG function), so you should find a library in .NET which transforms SVG into image and then save that somewhere. In the email you should refer to your image by url to your own storage.

Comment: @SebastianBochan thank you.  So I would call the webpage using something like WebClient and that webpage would have javascript in it that would return the SVG?  Is that what your saying?

Comment: Sorry, or that the server call would save the image automatically somewhere which I could then reference

Comment: Somehow, but maybe better is using somehting like this: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/render-charts-serverside in .net.